Cura Continues Crashing on Debian
I am attempting to use Cura as an app on my Chromebook using Debian Linux. I downloaded it from Flathub and have it installed on the computer. However, when I click on it, it brings up the little loading graphic and crashes when it gets to the "Loading UI" part. Even though I want to be able to access Cura from the app, I've also tried launching the file from my terminal. However, each time I try (./UltimakerCura.AppImage), it crashes and gives me a message that says the Wayland Compositor broke. I do not know what to do from here. Can anybody help?
